# How do I get distinct grouped data?

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

For the following table structure:

```
Name   |     ID
john       111111111
robert     222222222
robert     333333333
jack       444444444
stewart    555555555
stewart    666666666
lana       777777777
```

How can I return the following output using a select query:

```
john      111111111
robert    222222222
jack      444444444
steware   555555555
lana      777777777
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Name, Min(ID)
from table1
Group by name
```